# serial port close hangs in compact frame work 3.5

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, serial-port

I have developed the application for windows mobile 5.0 and .net compact framework 2.0 sp2. This application communicates to the hardware device using serial port. This application works fine in windows mobile 5.0 based PDAs. I have handled data received event to get the data from serial port.

But when I run my application on windows mobile 6.1 and .net compact framework 3.5, my application hangs on serial port close API call. There are many workarounds mentioned in the .net compact framework blog like (closing the com port on different thread, opening the port in the beginning of the application and close once application exists, polling for data instead of event handling), but nothing is working consistently.

Comment: Can you show some code that involves what you are doing? Have you checked out this http://opennetcf.com/, under Free Tools, there's OpenNetCF.IO.Serial here http://opennetcf.com/FreeSoftware/OpenNETCFIOSerial/tabid/252/Default.aspx.

Comment: a better link to it is http://serial.codeplex.com/